# How to indent jsp pages in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, text-editor

just started working with jsps and my pages look awful. Please suggest a way to have them indented.

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First make sure you have Web Tools installed, if not check this link:
http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/updates/

Then right click in your code of your jsp page and click source then click format or press SHIFT+CTRL+F

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [webtools plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/).

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl+I to indent the selected part (or all) of you code