# JSP pages in Eclipse do not indent?

Tags: eclipse, jsp, xhtml, ide

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231149/how-to-indent-jsp-pages-in-eclipse) article describing how to format jsp's in eclipse.  I have WTP installed and the jsp tags are colored.  However, there is no indenation on the html (i.e. `<html>` and `<body>` etc. are all at the same level).  I've tried Source -> Format with no success.  Is this a bug?

Comment: it seems to work for me on galileo with wtp 3.1

Comment: very weird, I have the same versions and cannot indent on jsp's...indentation works fine in xml and other formats though..

Answer (score 0):

- make sure you open the jsps with the JSP editor (`Right click > Open with`)
- open it and try `CTRL + SHIFT + F`
- get a fresh installation of eclipse (don't delete the current one), and try it there

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here 
Toy around with the formatter settings for html as this is used for jsp.

window > preferences > left tree pick web > editor.
Then change the line width to maybe 180
Click "Split multiple attributes each on a new line" seems to do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for writing soooo late, but I had the same problem, and I managed to solve It, and like me, maybe others don't know how.

Window -> Preferences -> left tree pick: General -> Editors -> Text Editors.

And change the "display the tab width" attribute to the desired value.

After this, "CTRL + SHIFT + F" should indent as expected for you.

This move was tested on Eclipse Helios. It may work for other versions as well.